# grep Commands in Unix

Tags: grep

Is there any difference between `grep “^[^a-z]” foo` and `grep –v “^[a-z]” foo`?

It displays the same output whereas the first command displays some highlighted characters. Is that the only difference?

Comment: Can you run the following command and post the output:  `alias grep`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I need to point out that your commands have been pasted into a word processor.  Please note that the quotes in your command are "curly quotes" and are not valid.

That aside the commands are almost equivalent.

```
grep "^[^a-z]" foo
```

`[^a-z]` is a regular expression to "Match a single character *not present* in the list".  So this command will match any line in the file `foo` that **does not** begin with a lowercase letter.

---

```
grep -v "^[a-z]" foo
```

`[a-z]` is a regular expression to "Match a single character *present* in the list", but the `-v` option is "invert-match" (Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.).  Therefore this will find any line in the file `foo` that **does not** start with a lowercase letter.  **Difference** this command will also match blank lines.